# Are there accommodations in the turbolifts for mute persons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

Suppose that a mute person enters a turbolift by him or herself, such as Riva ("Loud as a Whisper"). Since he cannot speak, would he be able to get to his destination? Could the destination of the traveler be entered into a control panel, for example? I don't necessarily recall such a control panel on the inside of the Enterprise-D turbolifts, though. I'm not sure about the other commands.

Comment: Not just mutes, I guess people in the future can still get laryngitis. Voice controls aren't all they're cracked up to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are panels both inside the turbolifts and just outside them at their entry points.

Inside:
[image]

Outside:
[image]

So a deaf or mute person can still use the turbolifts. Not sure how a person who is mute and blind would cope. (Maybe get a visor like Geordi and some ear implants?)

Answer (score 6):

It kind of stands to reason that the ship's internal systems can understand most forms of communication using the [Universal Translator](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/universal-translator).

> The computers of the U.S.S. Enterprise NCC-1701-D have translator capabilities built into its system software.

So it shouldn't matter if the turbo-lift occupant speaks English or waves flippers, the desired destination should be understood....

Comment: Waves flippers!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yep.  No reason why a humpback whale can't use a turbolift.  They're part of the Federation, aren't they?

Comment: Lieutenant Gracie :D

Comment: And the book on the Enterprise-D mentioned that dolphins were among the crew members.